# Outlook.Application not defined

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I have Microsofr Office Professional Plus 2010 version 14.0.6029.1 installed. 
I have the following reference in a VB project:

> Microsoft.Office.Enterop.Outlook

The type is .NET and the version id 14.0.0.0

My code includes the following:

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
```

the following error appears:

> "Error   14  Type 'Outlook.Application' is not defined.  "

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 6):

I'm in the process of upgrading several projects from XP to Win7 as well, and I ran into this problem a few weeks back.

Try this,

Go to `Project Properties -> References -> Add -> Click COM Tab -> Scroll down to either "Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library" or "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library".` (Pretty sure it needs to be the Outlook one).

In my solution, when I right click on `Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application` and go to definition, it is a member of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`, which comes from the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook DLL

This worked for me, so I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a namespace conflict with `Outlook` that the code is perhaps trying to reference a different object?

Try aliasing your `Imports` directive:

> Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Enterop.Outlook

This should explicitly tell your code (specifically your `Dim` statement) to use that namespace instead of any other implied `Outlook` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I replaced Imports Outlook with Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook and saw no change.

Comment: @Nate: I just noticed that my code sample was using `Interop` instead of `Enterop` like yours.  I've updated my answer, and it's worth trying again on your part.

Comment: I continued this line of thought by adding Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop and saw no change.

Comment: I checked my references. My use of "Enterop" in the question was a typo. The reference reads "Interop". That would have been typical for me though.

Comment: I have run this for two years on an XP Platform. I just swithced to a new machine with Windows 7.

Comment: @Nate: Ah, I thought it might just be a culture setting or something.  Googling around, this page presents an answer like mine but continues with some more links: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/381010-outlook-application-not-defined-pia-installed-setup-correctly, same here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/type-outlook-application-not-defiined-t1423369.html, and some other stuff here: http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=51467092  I guess I'm curious if the reference isn't somehow broken.  Can you navigate the classes in the object explorer?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Tell me how and I'll try it.

Comment: @Nate: In Visual Studio there should be something called the "Object Browser" (in 2010, maybe slightly different in other versions) under the "View" menu.  This should give you a visual hierarchy of classes and namespaces available to you.  You can browse through there to see if the imported library contains the class definitions.  It could be that the import it somehow broken and the code is otherwise fine.

Comment: Thanks, There are many items, perhaps several hundread, under Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. This leads me to believe whatever it needs is there. Evidently this discussion needs to be moved to a chat. I appreciate your time helping me with this. I am going to ga ahead and move it per request.

Comment: I guess I am not going to move this to chat. I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: One of your suggested sites had this comment "I have installed the PIA's and made
 sure they are pointing to the GAC."  I have not made sure the PIA's are pointed to the GAC as this individual has. I am not sure what they mean by this. Can you shed some light on this statment?

Comment: Based on comments I have seen I am going to un-install and re-install Office. If this doens' work I'll be back. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: OK! Un-nstalling and re-installing Office was the solution, however, it must be noted that any old references must also be removed from the solution properties or you will get ambiguity. Thanks again for your help Dave. I was dead in the water.

Answer (score 0):

for 2016 excel version make sure the below is ticked:

tools-->references----->
*Microsoft outlook 16.0 object library,
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library,
Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library.